# Why can't it not possible to find area from perimeter of an irregular polygon?

Tags: math, area

I have searched a lot of google, reviewed my old mathematics books, But I am stuck why can't we find area of an irregular shape from its perimeter? If we have find perimeter from area, Is that possible to reverse the process and find area from perimeter.

This process is working fine for square and rectangle but not for totally irregular shapes.
I'm asking this question because we have one field with irregular shape, and we want to know its area, We can measure its 5 sides.

Don't we have any method to find area from perimeter for irregular shapes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this question is off-topic here. Check [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The 'rope' winding analogy is a good one. You might also consider [triangular decomposition](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonirregulararea.html). Sadly, however - this is off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a rope and form an irregular shape. Measure it's area. Now change the shape you just formed with the rope. Measure the area again. Is it the same? Not necessarily.

Or consider a square and a rhomb (which is not a square) with the same perimeter. Do they have the same area? No. Therefore, how do you think could you find out what its area is if you don't have the information of the shape?

You cannot get the area if you just have the information of the perimeter, but don't know anything else.